# Right exception to throw for the lack of a system property

Tags: java

Say I have a system property `MY_PROP`:

```
java -DMY_PROP="My value"
```

This property is necessary for my system to work.

What is the right exception to throw if this property is not set?

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() {

    myProp = System.getProperty("MY_PROP");
    if (myProp == null) {
        throw new ????
    }
    // ...   
}
```

Somehow `IllegalArgumentException` does not feel right. Maybe `IllegalStateException`, `MissingResourceException`, `TypeNotPresentException`? What is the standard practice for this scenario?

Comment: Why don't you create your own exception? e.g. `MissingSystemPropertyException`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is none. I would throw the `IllegalStateException`, because you are missing the parameter. This mean that configuration validator has failed and your application is in invalid state. In other words you should never be able to call the `init()` at all.

In case the value of parameter would be invalid, then i would throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

If you are writing a validator, you should decide between using `RuntimeException` or checked one. When using for example javax.naming.ConfigurationException`, or created own one configuration exception. You API will be able to handle such exception and react properly in term of legacy.

Definitions:

**[IllegalStateException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html)** - Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.

**[IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html)** - Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument.

Comment: Maybe I should write a custom `MissingSystemPropertyException` that extends `IllegalStateException`?

Comment: There is absolutely no shame in creating subclass of IllegalStateException or RuntimeException. I wish more libraries did this instead of throwing generic exceptions like IllegalState, Runtime,IllegalArgument etc.

Comment: @AdamGent, You have right. I have slightly edited my answer. The checked exceptions has an issue on design level. They help but also limits. I have forgot about this for a moment. Thanks for remind.

Answer (score 5):

I only add to Vash's answer for the Spring Framework. If your using the Spring Framework and you want to be consistent with how most of the components in Spring do it then I would say you should use IllegalStateException (or your own derivation).

In Spring most components that do a `@PostConstruct` or `@Override void afterPropertiesSet()` throw `IllegalStateException` using the util `org.springframework.util.Assert.state(..)`.

You can see this done in [Spring AMQP](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.amqp/spring-rabbit/1.3.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java#338) as one example.

That being said I have actually filed bugs against Spring MVC [where they used IllegalArgumentException](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10226) instead of a custom and more explicit derived class. With static inline classes its very easy to create a custom exception with out creating another Java file.

Answer (score 1):

Because a system property is not always defined, the standard pratice is to use a default value when you can't find the property.

I just checked some standard code in java 7 (apache tomcat, java.lang, java.awt, ...), they always use a default "fallback" when the property is `null`.

So maybe your problem is somewhere else ?

Why don't you take this parameters as a required argument of your jar ? Then you can use `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Thanks for the input Magnus, but say that there is no sensible default for `MY_PROP`, I really want to throw an Exception (or an Error since the system will not be usable without this property). What would be the best exception to throw?

Comment: I think you should write your own exception. Because there's no standard exception for that (because it's not a standard pratice).